# How to combine SUM and MIN functions in the same formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table that has 3 different prices based on how someone orders a product. The 3 columns link to a base price. The cells in E81, F81, and G81 can changed based on an overall price decrease on another tab.

[image: min and sum example]

**Original formula**: =SUM(J81+(J81*Price!C3))

Problem is I do not want "Discount" to go below $25.00

**What I tried**: =MIN(25,SUM(J81+(J81*Price!C3)))

**Question**

How can I use the SUM function but set a minimum for the formula in the same cell?

Comment: `=MAX(25,SUM(J81+(J81*Price!C3)))`?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Thanks! That worked, can you put this as an answer so I can mark as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MIN` chooses the lowest of two values, setting a ceiling for any set of values.

To set a floor, you need to use `MAX`:

```
=MAX(25,SUM(J81+(J81*Price!C3)))
```